# How to get Dynamic Object Names WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

how can i dynamically get the Values of Textboxes?
I have Textboxes Named from textbox1 to 29

```
for (int i = 1; i < 29; i++)
        {
            
            
            CreateCSV2("textbox" + i .Text);
        }
```

I just cant figure it out.

Comment: You don't want to use numbered variables. If this is a UI framework like WinForms or WebForms, see duplicate.

Comment: Of course but how to do it in WPF?

Comment: If this is wpf you can use FindName() Method.  so change current line inside "for loop" with: CreateCSV2( (this.FindName("textbox" + i) as TextBox).Text)